# What is the best way to load and reuse api data for multiple routes in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state

I am currently designing a small react application that uses the react-router to build routes to multiple sections of the application. When the user hits the `/projects` route they select a project to work with which then sends them to the `/projects/:projectId/details` route and from there they can click a `<link>` to get to the `/projects/:projectId/config` route. A similar setup is done for the `/campaigns/:campaignId/*` routes.

```
<Switch>
   {/*Dashboard*/}
   <Route exact path="/projects" component={ProjectFind}/>
   <Route exact path="/campaigns" component={CampaignFind}/>

   {/*Projects*/}
   <Redirect exact from='/projects/:projectId' to='/projects/:projectId/details'/>
   <Route exact path="/projects/:projectId/details" component={ProjectDetails}/>
   <Route exact path="/projects/:projectId/details/config" component={ProjectConfig}/>
   ... More Project Routes here ...

   {/*Campaigns*/}
   <Redirect exact from='/campaigns/:campaignId' to='/campaigns/:campaignId/details'/>
   <Route exact path="/campaigns/:campaignId/details" component={CampaignDetails}/>
   <Route exact path="/campaigns/:campaignId/details/config" component={CampaignConfig}/>
   ... More Campaign Routes Here ...
</Switch>
```

Currently I am loading the data for the project or campaign based on the router params on each page in a `useEffect` hook and using `useState` to store the data for that page.

The issue with that is that I'm fetching the same data every time the user switches between the different `/projects/:projectId/*` routes and that data doesn't actually change very often so it is wasted api calls. There are about 15 routes

What I'd like to do is figure out how to only fetch the data once, regardless of which route they hit first ( in case they bookmark a page and go to it directly ) and then be able to reuse that same data for all the other matching routes.

Comment: Sounds like a case for redux. You could also look into using reacts context api.

Comment: @A.Larsson i have been looking at redux but finding it difficult to understand for this particular use case. All the examples are very simplistic and don't deal with data loaded from an api which makes it harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cache inside your hooks to store the data with respect to id.

```
import React from 'react';

const cache = {};

function useApi(id) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (cache[id]) {
      // if the data is already in the cache
      // use the cache
      setData(cache[id])

    } else {
      // do you api here 
      fetch("your api call here")

      // after the data is fetched.
      // update your cache
      cache[id] = data;
      // update your state
      setData(data);
    }
  }, [id, setData]);

  return data;
}
```